# Autowiring tcp-outbound-channel-adapter using Id does not work

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I am trying to autowire my `tcp-inbound-channel-adapter` bean defined as below. Later I will be starting this on certain conditions.

```
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="inboundClient" channel="replies" connection-factory="client"
    client-mode="true"  auto-startup="false" retry-interval="10000" />
```

Autowiring as:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("inboundClient")
TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundClient;
```

My `inboundClient` is always `null`.

However when I do something as below, it works, without NPE, `tc` has object reference and starts the inbound adapter and receives data.

```
TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tc = (TcpReceivingChannelAdapter)
      context.getBean("inboundClient");
      Thread.sleep(5000); 
      tc.start();
```

Please let me know, if you have come across this or solved this.

EDIT:

I have my code posted here:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">



<context:component-scan base-package="com.tcpclient" />
<context:annotation-config />
<!--Deserializer for incoming data on the socket -->

<bean
    class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer"
    id="serializeAndDeserializer">
    <constructor-arg type="byte" value="0" />
</bean>



<!-- TCP Client configuration -->

<!-- Channels for communication -->

<int:channel id="tcp-client-input" />

<int:channel id="message" />

<int:channel id="message-serviceActivator" />

<int:gateway id="gateway" service-interface="com.tcpclient.ClientGateway"
    default-request-channel="tcp-client-input" default-reply-channel="message" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="clientFactory"
    type="client" host="10.255.233.21" port="1234" single-use="false"
    so-timeout="10000" deserializer="serializeAndDeserializer" serializer="serializeAndDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="outBoundClient" channel="tcp-client-input" connection-factory="clientFactory"
    retry-interval="60000" auto-startup="false" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="inBoundClient" channel="message" connection-factory="clientFactory"
    client-mode="true" auto-startup="false" retry-interval="60000" />


<int:object-to-string-transformer
    input-channel="message" output-channel="message-serviceActivator" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="message-serviceActivator"
    method="onRtlsMessageArrival">
    <bean class="com.tcpclient.HandleRtlsMessage" />
</int:service-activator></beans>
```

### Config manager:

```
@component
public class RtlsConfigManager {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("inBoundClient")
  TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundClient;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("outBoundClient")
  TcpSendingMessageHandler outBoundClient;

  public void initialize(Boolean canStart) {

    try {
      if (canStart) {
        inboundClient.start();
        outBoundClient.start();  
      }  
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Error occured while fetching data.");
    }
  }

}
```

### Stack trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=outBoundClient)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

If I take off below from existing code

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("outBoundClient")
TcpSendingMessageHandler outBoundClient;
```

and

```
outBoundClient.start();
```

it starts my **inBoundClient**

Am I trying to autowire outBoundClient in a wrong way. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Use four spaces to make a code block, not backticks.

Comment: You need to show more code/configuration - it looks like the class you are trying to autowire into is not itself a bean. Edit the question with more details.

Comment: @Gary I have added some more details.

Comment: You need to show the class and bean definition into which you are autowiring the adapter. `context.getBean()` will work in the class that creates the context; but for autowiring, the class has to be a bean as well.

Comment: @Gary please have a look at my posted details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject these beans with type `SmartLifeCycle` not the `TcpSendingMessageHandler` type. The receiving adapter will work that way, though but since you want to use the lifecycle stuff it's better to narrow the type.

The sending handler actually has a bean name `outBoundClient.handler` but that's not what you want to start/stop, it is wrapped in a consumer (which implements `SmartLifecyle` and the type depends on the channel type; in this case, an `EventDrivenConsumer`).